# How to map non-primitive jdk classes with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

For example I have class with next description

```
public class Entity{
 private Integer id;
 private DataSource ds;
}
```

Is it possible to map ds field with hibernate? If yes, how I can do it?

**Updated**

Generally, I have next problem: my app has many customers(companies) and each one has his own database. I would like to use hibernate multitenancy. I wrote next class for hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider property

```
public class MyMultiTenantConnectionProvider extends AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider{

@Autowired
private DataSource defaultDS;

@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;

@Override
protected ConnectionProvider getAnyConnectionProvider() {
    DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl ds = new DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl();
    ds.setDataSource(defaultDS);
    return ds;
}

@Override
protected ConnectionProvider selectConnectionProvider(String tenantIdentifier) {
    DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl ds = new DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl();
    ds.setDataSource(customerService.getDataSourceByTenantId(tenantIdentifier));
    return ds;
}
```

May be, it's wrong way. But i didn't see any examples, which will good for my application.

Comment: sounds like an XY problem. why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to have a `DataSource` as a field in an entity? That is strange. How should that be mapped to a database column in your idea?